# post a value of name in href to another php page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to change text mark picked to mark delivered on click a link and  post  $oid data to updategoingorder.php.

```js
$(".waves-effect3").click(function() {
  var addressValue = $(this).attr("id");
  var oid = $(this).attr("name");
  $(".waves-effect3").text("Mark Delivered");
});
alert(oid);
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'updategoingorder.php',
  data: {
    'id': addressValue,
    'name': oid
  },
  success: function() {

    alert("Status Updated!!!");
  }
});
});
```

```html
<td><a href="#" name="'.$oid.'" class="waves-effect3" id="'.$data[$i]['name'].'"><i class="fa fa-check"></i><span>Mark Picked</span></a>
  <br>
```

Comment: When do you call the Ajax? It looks like you need to remove `});
alert(oid);`

Comment: thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".waves-effect3").click(function() {
              var addressValue = $(this).attr("id");
              var oid = $(this).attr("name");
              $(".waves-effect3").text("Mark Delivered");
            });
            alert(oid);
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'updategoingorder.php',
                  data: {
                'id': addressValue,
                'name': oid
                  },
                  success: function() {

                alert("Status Updated!!!");
                  }
                });
            });
            });
```

Comment: Do you think you will be able to access `addressValue` and `oid` outside the click function ?

Comment: No. It will not be accessible.

Comment: Then what's the meaning of posting an wrong answer even you know that will not work.

Answer (score 1):

your code seems fine, except few problems,

- Ajax function should be inside the `click function()`
- you won't be able to access variables `addressValue, oid` outside of the function.

```js
$(".waves-effect3").click(function() {
   var addressValue = $(this).attr("id");
   var oid = $(this).attr("name");
   console.log(oid);  
   console.log(addressValue);
   $(".waves-effect3").text("Mark Delivered");
  
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'updategoingorder.php',
      data: {
        'id': addressValue,
        'name': oid
      },
      success: function() {
        alert("Status Updated!!!");
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><a href="#" name="dummy" class="waves-effect3" id="10"><i class="fa fa-check"></i><span>Mark Picked</span></a>
  <br>
```

Comment: can u help me out to change order status from dispatched to  picked and then delivered from an API.

Comment: You should create new question as you might have different problem, not related with this